# Elasticsearch error when running Sonarqube 6.7 on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_161 as the Java runtime. When I run the `StartSonar.bat` I get the following exception:

```
 2018.01.17 11:27:10 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\jguzmanb\Downloads\sonar\temp
`enter code here`2018.01.17 11:27:10 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:22412
2018.01.17 11:27:10 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\Users\jguzmanb\Downloads\sonar\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\Users\jguzmanb\Downloads\sonar\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=C:\Users\jguzmanb\Downloads\sonar\temp\conf\es
2018.01.17 11:27:10 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.01.17 11:27:10 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.01.17 11:27:10 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.01.17 11:27:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2018.01.17 11:27:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\Users\jguzmanb\Downloads\sonar]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\jguzmanb\Downloads\sonar\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\Users\jguzmanb\Downloads\sonar\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\jguzmanb\Downloads\sonar\temp\sq-process8452829030556415962properties
2018.01.17 11:27:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2018.01.17 11:27:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.01.17 11:27:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2018.01.17 11:27:24 WARN  app[][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x8620473c, L:/127.0.0.1:22466 - R:/127.0.0.1:22412]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:433)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018.01.17 11:27:24 WARN  app[][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x8623fc7c, L:/127.0.0.1:22464 - R:/127.0.0.1:22412]], closing connection
```

My properties file:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATABASE Mysql
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&useSSL=false
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEB SERVER
sonar.web.host=localhost
TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
sonar.web.port=9000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ELASTICSEARCH
sonar.search.port=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need to translate "Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto" in English. Did you try using other port numbers (not used by others)?

Comment: From the logs, I would rather be looking for an error with the web process. Please have a look in web.log.

Comment: In english....An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
I try change the elasticSearch port, and i got the same error too

sonar.search.port=0 is in the properties file

Comment: could you check logs/es.log please ?

Comment: In  web.log i found the problem, thanx

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. How do you resolve it? Where is the file web.log? Thanks

Comment: Please make an answer to provide the solution to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your web log file inside the logs folder(C:\sonarqube\logs).
Sonarqube is trying to use a port which is already occupied, force kill the port worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On the loglevel, you can see that this is a WARN message.

The real error is caused by something else.

Check the `sonarqube\logs` folder for details.